# Can't make conditional style in tikz work

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I defined a macro `\chooseStyle{text}{styleA}{styleB}` which chooses between `styleA` and `styleB` depending on the text (it simply returns the good style). I tried to incorporate it into a tikz style using:

```
  styleA/.style={...},
  styleA/.style={...},
  choose/.code={
    \tikzset{\chooseStyle{#1}{styleA}{styleB}}
  }
```

but it fails (like many other attemps) with errors. What's wrong?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% Small minus. Feel free to redefine.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zxMinus}{\mathbin}{AMSa}{"39} % Requires amssymb
\tikzset{
  %% Can be redefined by user
  % Style for empty nodes
  styleA/.style={fill=green},
  % Style for nodes that are small enough to fit in a circle, like $\zxMinus \frac{\pi}{4}$
  styleB/.style={fill=red},
  % Style that chooses which style to apply depending on the input text
  choose/.code={
    %% Fails (error):
    \tikzset{\chooseStyle{#1}{styleA}{styleB}}
    %% Fails (error):
    % \expandafter\tikzset{\chooseStyle{#1}{styleA}{styleB}}
    %% Fails (bad style applied)
    % \ifthenelse{\equal{\chooseStyle{#1}{styleA}{styleB}}{styleA}}{\tikzset{styleA}}{\tikzset{styleB}}
  },
}


\makeatletter
\newsavebox\zx@box % Temporary box to compute height/width/depth

\NewDocumentCommand{\chooseStyle}{mmm}{%
  % #1=text,#2=empty style,#3=other style
  \savebox\zx@box{#1}%
  % Check if width is 0pt:
  \ifdimcomp{\wd\zx@box}{=}{0pt}{% Return empty style if box is empty
    #2% Empty style
  }{%
    #3 % other style
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chooseStyle{}{styleA}{styleB}
\chooseStyle{abc}{styleA}{styleB}

\begin{tikzcd}
  \node[choose=]{}; % Should display a green node
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{` won't add any new non expandable constructs but it can not magically turn a command doing typesetting into a box into something expandable, Why are you using `\savebox` here????

Comment: I'm using `\savebox` because in real life I check if the height/width of text is bigger than some constants.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So what's the solution if `NewExpandableDocumentCommand` is not working? I tried `\newcommand`, it's not better.

Comment: if you want a non expandable test then I would guess you need to move it out of tikzset, so dont do`\tikzset{if something A else B}` do `if something \tikzset{A} else \tikzset{B}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I tried with `\ifthenelse{}{}{}` but it fails. That said, I'd prefer the test to be inside the `\tikzset`, and I don't really want non-expandable test, it's just that `NewExpandableDocumentCommand` it proved to work better in other context so I started to use it everywhere ^^' But changing it to `NewDocumentCommand` gives other errors (ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.)

Comment: I'll let others more familiar with tikz answer but using newexpandabledocumentcommand here looks structurally very wrong, it is clever code (parsing for optional arguments without adding non expandable constructs) but here you are not parsing for optional arguments and the replacement text is as far from expansion as possible as it involves typesetting and assignment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I changed the code to use newdocumentcommand, now error is `ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.`